# Bootstrap v4 impact of reducing the navbar size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I reduced the navbar size in bootstrap v4. It worked fine but few issues. Can some one help me fix this critical issue. At least the 2nd one is very crucial to fix.

1, On toggle (in small screens) the background color gets lost.

2, There is lot of space between navbar and subsequent body element, could not cut down the space.[image]

```
<style>
    .navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:8px !important; padding-bottom:1px !important;}
    .navbar input {height:25px !important; font-size:12px !important;width:400px; }
    input {font-size:12px !important;}
    .navbar {min-height:15px !important; max-height:28px !important}
    body{font-size:12px !important;font-family:}



</style>
```

HTML Code:

```
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template <link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="/static/smapy/starter.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- for admin widget 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/smapy/main.js"></script> 




<style>
    .navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:8px !important; padding-bottom:1px !important;}
    .navbar input {height:25px !important; font-size:12px !important;width:400px; }
    input {font-size:12px !important;}
    .navbar {min-height:15px !important; max-height:28px !important}
    body{font-size:12px !important;font-family:}



</style>

<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 6) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/sm/search/?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

(function(){

  $("#cart").on("click", function() {
    $(".shopping-cart").fadeToggle( "fast");
  });

})();
</script> 


  </head>

  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;" >
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="/static/image/smlogo.png" width="140" height="26" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">

            </a>    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        </ul>
   <ul class="navbar-nav">

      <li class="dropdown" style="padding-right:13px;"  >
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> 
          <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-1x"></span> Cart <span class="cartcount" id="cart_count">0</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart" role="menu">
            <!--  <li >
                  <span class="item">
                    <span class="item-left">
                        <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/menucartdropdown/item_1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="item-info">
                            <span>Item name</span>
                            <span>price: 27$</span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="item-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger  fa fa-close"></button>
                    </span>
                </span>
              </li>  -->   
          </ul>
       </li> 


        <form method="get" action="/search/" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input name="q" id="id_q" value="" class="form-control mr-sm-0" type="text" placeholder="pin code or Shop Name to search" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
          <!-- <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button> -->
        </form>


            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">esakki</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounts/logout/">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/vendor/">Shopowner? Register here.</a>
          </li>



         </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

<style>
.breadcrumb li{
display: inline;

}
</style> 







<div class="container">


<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9"> 
<h3>shopmapy welcomes you!</h3>

    <p>Your Neighbourhood Shopping Destination. </p>
 <div class="container">
       <br>



 Django!! </div>
```

Comment: post the html too

Comment: @ZimSystem I have added